# Bounded solutions implies the zero solution is absolutely stable

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the homogeneous, linear, autonomous differential equation
$ Y'(t)=A Y(t) $.

I want to show that if every solution to a linear homogeneous system is bounded as $t$ goes to infinity, then the zero solution is stable.

I'm am not quite sure on how to use the assumption of boundedness in order to create this proof. I thought of using the statement that says if the eigenvalues of $A$ all have negative real part then all the solutions are bounded. However I am only interested in the zero solution.

Comment: The claim is not correct. Consider $y' = iy$. Then the solutions are of the form $y(t) = ce^{it}$. Each of these is bounded, but does not tend to zero, as close as you might want to place $c$ to zero.

Comment: An example with real coefficients is $A = \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1\\-1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$.

Comment: You are talking about Asymptotically stable. I do not require the zero solution to be Asymptotically stable: I just want it to be stable, which it is in your first case.

Comment: So, what about the title of this topic???

Comment: I agree the topic is quite foolish, do not know why I wrote that

Comment: Maybe it helps you that all eigenvalues of $A$ have non-positive real parts. Indeed, suppose there exists an eigenvalue $z$ of $A$ with positive real part. Choose a corresponding eigenvector $x$ and put $Y(t) := e^{zt}x$. Then $Y$ is an unbounded solution. Contradiction.